# ROC curve interpretation

Tags: curve, roc

I have a question regarding the ROC curve. The question is: Order the points A, B, C w.r.t the accuracy of the classifier (from good to weak).
I know the ROC curve shows the relation of true positive rate and false positive rate.
But I am not sure how to answer the question above and also how to justify it.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are A, B and C representing?

Comment: Points on each of the curves.